# T61 ThinkPad, Ubuntu 10.04.2, fixed address, no connection

Tags: networking, thinkpad

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed on my desktop computer which has a device with a fixed address connected to a gigabit port which has a fixed address assigned to it. They happily communicate. Now I am trying to get the same application running on a ThinkPad T61 with the same device. I have Ubuntu 10.04.2 loaded on the T61. The ethernet port on the T61 communicates nicely with a router using DHCP. However, when I try assigning a fixed address the ethernet interface becomes inactive. I have tried editing the file /etc/network/interfaces to include appropriate information for having eth0 have a fixed address. That doesn't work. I am looking for some fresh ideas.

Comment: What was/is the contents of /etc/network/interfaces and is there any information from the dmesg command, you can post the files and debug info on http://paste.ubuntu.com/  Does the command `sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0` fix the problem?? of cause you need to use appropriate ip/netmask for your network.

Answer (score 1):

you mean a static ip address? what happens when you do..

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.100.107 down

ifconfig eth0 up
```

Comment: Nothing happens.